# Procedure multiplicar

Tags: procedure

Estou precisando de ajudar para resolver um problema,

Código:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure sp_ptopedido( TPOMEDIOREPOS int, DEMANDA int, ESTOQUEMINIMO int),
begin

    PONTOPEDIDOTOPEDIDO = ((TPOMEDIOREPOS / 30) * DEMANDA) + ESTOQUEMINIMO FROM produto;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Obtenho este erro ao executar o comando:

Comando SQL:

```
create procedure sp_ptopedido( TPOMEDIOREPOS int, DEMANDA int, ESTOQUEMINIMO int),
begin

    PTOPEDIDO = ((TPOMEDIOREPOS / 30) * DEMANDA) + ESTOQUEMINIMO FROM produto;

END
```

Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' begin
>
> ```
>     PTOPEDIDO = ((TPOMEDIOREPOS / 30) * DEMANDA) + ESTOQUEMINIMO ' at line 1
> ```

Comment: Ola Maria, vc poderia ser mais especifica em relação ao problema, explica mais sobre ele e acrescentar mais detalhes, isso ajudaria. Faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) também para aprender como o site funciona.

Comment: oi Dener, essa procedure faria esse calculo:Ponto de Pedido = [(Tempo de Reposição/30) * Demanda] + Estoque Mínimo.

Comment: Dai tentei fazer aquele código, mas que está dando erro.

Comment: os campos DEMANDA, ESTOQUEMINIMO E TPOMEDIOREPOS são da mesma tabela, produtos.

Comment: Qual erro esta dando? Poderia editar a pergunta e colocar os erros?

Comment: Qual linguagem esta utilizando também?

Comment: MySQL, estou fazendo no phpMyAdmim

Comment: Existe uma vírgula à mais depois do "(" da create procedure. Além disso você não faz nada com essa rotina além de atribuir a uma variável inexistente (PTOPEDIDO) um valor e não retorna nada para ninguém. Essa procedure, inclusive, me parece totalmente desnecessária para realizar algo tão simples, provavelmente o que você quer fazer é executar um UPDATE. Se você editasse a pergunte explicando seu problema, poderia obter melhor ajuda.